# Proof for a Set Being Topology of Another

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

$\newcommand{\ball}[3]{B_{#1}\left(#2, #3\right)}$
$\newcommand{\powerset}[1]{\mathcal{P}\left(#1\right)}$

First we have definition for topology: Let $\Omega \neq \emptyset$. A class $\tau$ is a topology on $\Omega$ if (1) $\tau \subseteq \powerset{\Omega}$; (2) $\emptyset \in \tau$ and $\Omega \in \tau$; (3) for any $A, B \in \tau$, $A \cap B \in \tau$; (4) for any $\mathcal{F}$, if $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \tau$, then $\bigcup \mathcal{F} \in \tau$ ($\powerset{\Omega}$ stands for power set of $\Omega$).

Next we have definition for open ball: let $\left(\Omega, d\right)$ be a metric space. Then for any $x \in \Omega$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$,
\begin{equation*}
\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} = \left\{y \in \Omega \vert d\left(x, y\right) < r\right\}.
\end{equation*}

It is my desire to prove the following theorem: let $\Omega \neq \emptyset$ and
\begin{equation*}
\tau = \left\{\bigcup\left\{\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} \vert \left(x, r\right) \in F\right\} \vert F \subseteq \Omega \times \left(0, \infty\right)\right\}.
\end{equation*}
Then $\tau$ is a topology on $\Omega$.

My proof goes as follows: First we prove $\tau \subseteq \powerset{\Omega}$. Let $A \in \tau$. Then there is some $F$ such that $F \subseteq \Omega \times \left(0, \infty\right)$ and that $A = \bigcup\left\{\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} \vert \left(x, r\right) \in F\right\}$. That is to say, there are some $S$ and $T$ such that $S \subseteq \Omega$, $T \subseteq \left(0, \infty\right)$ and $A = \bigcup\left\{\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} \vert x \in S \textrm{ and } r \in T\right\}$. Let $S$ and $T$ be sets such that $S \subseteq \Omega$, $T \subseteq \left(0, \infty\right)$ and $A = \bigcup\left\{\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} \vert x \in S \textrm{ and } r \in T\right\}$. Let $s \in A$. By definition, there are some $x \in S$ and $r \in T$ such that $s \in \ball{\Omega}{x}{r}$. Let $x \in S$ and $r \in T$ such that $s \in \ball{\Omega}{x}{r}$. As $\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} \subseteq \Omega$, it is clear that $s \in \Omega$. Thus, $A \subseteq \Omega$. As a result, for any $A \in \tau$, $A \in \powerset{\Omega}$. It is then clear that $\tau \subseteq \powerset{\Omega}$.

Next, we prove $\emptyset \in \tau$ and $\Omega \in \tau$. Let $K \subseteq \left(0, \infty\right)$. It is clear that $\emptyset \subseteq \Omega$. Then $\emptyset \times K \subseteq \Omega \times \left(0, \infty\right)$. As a result,
\begin{equation*}
\bigcup \left\{\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} \vert \left(x, r\right) \in \emptyset \times K\right\} \in \tau.
\end{equation*}
As $\emptyset \times K = \emptyset$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\bigcup \left\{\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} \vert \left(x, r\right) \in \emptyset \times K\right\} = \bigcup \left\{\emptyset\right\} = \emptyset.
\end{equation*}
Thus, $\emptyset \in \tau$. Further, as $\Omega \times \left(0, \infty\right) \subseteq \Omega \times \left(0, \infty\right)$, it is clear that
\begin{equation*}
\bigcup\left\{\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} \vert \left(x, r\right) \in \Omega \times \left(0, \infty\right)\right\} \in \tau.
\end{equation*}
Further, we have
\begin{equation*}
\bigcup\left\{\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} \vert \left(x, r\right) \in \Omega \times \left(0, \infty\right)\right\} = \Omega.
\end{equation*}
As a result, $\Omega \in \tau$.

Next, it is my purpose to prove that $\tau$ is $\cap$-closed. Formally, I need to prove the following lemma: assume that $\Omega \neq \emptyset$, $\Omega_{1} \subseteq \Omega$, $\Omega_{2} \subseteq \Omega$, $K_{1} \subseteq \left(0, \infty\right)$ and $K_{2} \subseteq \left(0, \infty\right)$. Let
\begin{equation*}
S = \bigcup\left\{\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} \vert x \in \Omega_{1}, r \in K_{1}\right\}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
T = \bigcup\left\{\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} \vert x \in \Omega_{2}, r \in K_{2}\right\}.
\end{equation*}
Then there is some $\Omega_{3}$ and $K_3$ such that $\Omega_{3} \subseteq \Omega$, $K_{3} \subseteq K$ and that
\begin{equation*}
S \cap T = \bigcup\left\{\ball{\Omega}{x}{r} \vert x \in \Omega_{3}, r \in K_{3}\right\}.
\end{equation*}

I am stuck at proving the above lemma for $\cap$-closed. Specifically, I do not know how to construct $\Omega_{3}$ and $K_{3}$. Any advice?

Comment: Your method can't work.  You are essentially forcing arbitrary subset of $\Omega\times(0,\infty)$ to be a rectangle $\Omega_i\times K_i$.